# A square matrix over a field $K$ is semi-simple if and only if it is diagonalizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

A square matrix over a field $K$ is semi-simple if and only if it is diagonalizable.

A matrix $A$ is semi-simple if the minimal polynomial of S has only simple roots. But unfortunately I cannot relate this with it being diagonalizable...help needed!

Comment: If $K$ is algebraically closed, look at Jordan canonical form, and it's immediate.